# Can you prepare and execute an IF statement using CONCAT()

Tags: mysql

I am trying to prepare an IF statement using `CONCAT()` that would then be prepared and executed within a MySQL procedure.  The reason for trying this is that it would be carried out within a loop and varible names would change with each loop.

To simply test this, I have attempted to create the code to ensure it works before incorporating updated variable names.

Is it possible to write `CONCAT IF` statements and then prepare and execute them?

My code is as follows:

```
SET @x = CONCAT('IF @Private > 0 THEN SET @Private = 100; ', 
        'ELSEIF @Private = 0 THEN SET @Private = 0; ',
        'ELSE SET @Private = 200; ',
        'END IF'
        );

PREPARE stmt FROM @x;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

I would expect the IF statement to be executed, however I get the error:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use

Comment: The prepared statement which you execute still has to be valid regular MySQL syntax, which your SQL is not.  You can only do this from a stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks - yes, to confirm: this is done within a stored procedure.

Comment: A standalone if statement is not valid sql.

Comment: Try [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=eaafe44ef365f12b38397c2b7ec34dd3).